# Why did Wigans say, "No car batteries this time"?

Tags: bloodshot-2020

After boss fight, Bloodshot wakes up:

> Wigans: Relax. Relax. Take it easy. **No car batteries this time.**

Why did Wigans say, "No car batteries this time"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the context of this involving Bloodshot waking up from being revived, I'm pretty sure that what's being implied is that his heart has been restarted and, as per [the TV Tropes entry for the Magic Defibrillator](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagicalDefibrillator), they're implying "shocking the flatline" with an improvised defibrillator. Specifically, they used regular medical techniques (and his nanotechnology) to bring him back rather than improvising something in the field.